# libglib2.0-0 dependens

Tags: dpkg, 19.10

after I installed libglib2.0-0 I cant run most applications, only Xvt terminal and when I try to remove I get dependens error. I cant copy/paste from Xvt because a known bug.
A lot of...

```
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.61.2) but 2.56.4-0ubu
bglib2.0-0 (>=2.61.2) but 2.59.2-0ubu is to be instaled.
After 24 rows like these I get Try apt --fix-broken install. 
When try the --fix-broken I get. Errors where encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-0_2.62.4-1 ubutnut19.10.2_amd64.deb
Error Timeout was reached
Subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help. It happened when I run dpkg -i libglib2.0...

Thank You

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Yes. Same problem... Here is the output https://imgur.com/hOuOtfQ

Comment: What is your current Ubuntu version? Was it upgraded? To get more reproducible results please run `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f` and add text output to the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by moving the trying to overwrite dir/file as root

```
mv /usr/share/doc/libglib2.0-0 /usr/share/doc/libglib2.0-0.backup
```

then `sudo apt-get install -f` pass successful